# Hibernate Query List inside an Object

Tags: java, hibernate, list, mapping, one-to-many

I have a class

```
public class Human{

  @OneToMany
  private List<Pets> myPets;
  //other fields here.
}
```

Is is it possible to query the human class and get the human with the most number of pets? can Hibernate/HQL do this or do I have to manualy get all humans and query list of pets they contain?? if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL allows you to query on the size of a list as follows:

```
select max(h.myPets.size) from Human h
```

You can therefore use this as a inner statement to find the human object(s) whose pet.size is equal to the max:

```
from Human h where h.myPets.size = (select max(h2.myPets.size) from Human h2)
```

Comment: can you explainyour code, it finally worked but a little explanation would not hurt